# rowspan not working while adding Html tables with rowspan using Html::addHtml() in php word library

Tags: phpword

this is my code in controller function. Here im adding html table to word document but in doc rowspan not getting. Please help me..

```
enter code here

   $phpWord = new PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    $test = '<table style="border: 1px solid black">
       <tr >
          <th style="border: 1px solid black">Month</th>
          <th style="border: 1px solid black">Savings</th>
          <th style="border: 1px solid black">Savings for holiday!</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black">January</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black">$100</td>
          <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black">$50</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black">February</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black">$80</td>
       </tr>
    </table>';
    Html::addHtml($section_last, $test);
....
```